# Python - Find the difference in two csv given the threshold values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, extract

I have two csv, one is excerpted from other. I want to compare two csv and have a new csv with difference between them. Orignally i used implemented sets and compare both. if both set don't mactch appended to new file. however i ran to issue that with slight change in number it is showing difference in both the files. is there a way to write the code memory efficient way where it compares the cell value and if the difference is more than 2 then it appends the row. 
following are the sample:

code that i have used is as below:

```
orig = open('T1.csv','r')
new = open('T2.csv','r')
bigb = set(new) - set(orig)

print(bigb)  
with open('different.csv', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in bigb:
        file_out.write(line)
orig.close()    
new.close()
```

file_out.close()

```
enter code here
```

```html
csv1:
0 1.1 -19.1 -29.1
1 2.1 -18.1 -28.1
2 3.1 -17.1 -27.1
3 4.1 -16.1 -26.1
4 5.1 -15.1 -25.1
5 6.1 -14.1 -24.1
6 7.1 -13.1 -23.1
7 8.1 -12.1 -22.1
8 9.1 -11.1 -21.1
9 10.1 -10.1 -20.1
10 11.1 -9.1 -19.1

csv2:
0 1.4 -19.6 -29.8
1 2.4 -18.6 -28.8
2 3.4 -17.6 -27.8
3 4.4 -16.6 -26.8
4 5.4 -15.6 -25.8
5 6.4 -14.6 -24.8
6 7.4 -13.6 -23.8
7 8.4 -12.6 -22.8
8 9.4 -11.6 -21.8
9 10.4 -10.6 -20.8
10 11.4 -9.6 -19.8
```

Comment: Could you replace the images with sample csv text? It will be usefull to test with

Comment: not sure how to do it.

Comment: nevermind, you did it correctly. Just to clear things out here, are you referring to  ```row``` difference or ```cell```difference. I mean you want to discard rows that appear in both files rounding the cell values to 2 decimal points ?

Comment: @kareem_emad i mean to say if the difference in cell is less than 2 then disregard it.

Comment: ok, if we have one row containing 4 cells, 3 of which are not matching and one is  matching, that means you will take that row as  ```c1 c2 c3 None``` right?

Comment: Also in the case of not matching, if c1 from first file is not matching c1 from second file, then what should I place in c1 in output. It will helpfull if you provided a sample of your desired output

Comment: @kareem_emad if any one of the cell is not matching more than 2 then return the whole row. Iam working in file with dimension 80k*1k. most of the values are similar to one decimal. Iam looking for how closely my excerpted file is.

Comment: @ganeshghimire you meant to say, more than 2 cells are different? Please give an example of your expected output based on `csv1` and `csv2`. Because currently, the differences are the same for every row, can't infer what you want.